# UIViewController doesn't seem to be fully released with ARC

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, automatic-ref-counting

The first view inside my application will only need to be shown once.

I am using the following inside a custom segue, to get it off the Navigation Controllers Stack and transition to the new one:

```
- (void)perform {
    UINavigationController *nav = [self.sourceViewController navigationController];
    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:self.destinationViewController];
    [nav setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:YES];
}
```

While I was able to confirm, that the `dealloc` method gets called, the memory usage doesn't go down. I am 100% certain, that the memory was allocated by the ViewController, that I would expect to be released, since it contains a pretty big image (UIImageView) and the other view controller is tiny (memory-wise).

I am also sure, that I am not holding any references to the contained elements anywhere else.

Could it be that UIImageView keeps the image in memory, in case it would be needed again?

Is what I am doing even a good way to go? (I was inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580948/push-view-controller-without-stacking))

Comment: How did you load the image? `imageNamed` will cache the image, holding until there's memory pressure. If you use `imageWithData` or `imageWithContentsOfFile`, it won't be cached.

Comment: The image was loaded through a storyboard file. Is there any way to simulate memory pressure on an actual device (not the simulator)? As of right now I need location services to be enabled. Therefore no testing in the simulator is possible. Of course, a non location service enabled alternative is on the to do list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a result of a quick test, I infer that image views that have images set in Interface Builder appear to be doing some caching. I assume it's the same caching mechanism used by `imageNamed`, whose [documentation says](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW10):

> If you have an image file that will only be displayed once and wish to ensure that it does not get added to the system’s cache, you should instead create your image using `imageWithContentsOfFile:`. This will keep your single-use image out of the system image cache, potentially improving the memory use characteristics of your app.

I don't know of any way to simulate the memory pressure that will cause this cache to be purged (other than obviously doing sufficient allocations to result in actual memory pressure). The various caches don't generally respond to the simulator's "Simulate Memory Warning" strangely enough, even though they do respond to true memory pressure. (Besides, you're testing on physical devices because of location services.)

But you can test to see if this indeed the issue by not setting the image in Interface Builder, but rather do it programmatically (and do it without using `imageNamed`), e.g.:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"imagename" ofType:@"png"];
self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

In my test, when I dismiss a scene in which the image was set in Interface Builder, I do not recover as much memory as I do when I use the above code instead.